# Create SQL Server DSN

Tags: c#, dsn

I am needing to create a DSN through code to connect with SQL Server.  I tried the example in this link, but it always fails as the dataSourceKey is never null.  Does someone have a different solution or another option?

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/350601/Create-SQL-DSN-in-Csharp

And this is the code:

```
string ODBC_PATH = "SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\";     
string driverName = "SQL Server";
string dsnName = "DSNfromCode";
string database = "MyDBName";
string description = "This DSN was created from code!";
//This is one change I made the source code had the IP of the server and I 
//am hardcoding a server name
string server = "Brimstone";
bool trustedConnection = false;

// Lookup driver path from driver name         
string driverPath = "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\sqlsrv32.dll"; 

var datasourcesKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ODBC_PATH + "ODBC Data Sources");         
if (datasourcesKey == null) 
{
throw new Exception("ODBC Registry key does not exist"); 
}        
    datasourcesKey.SetValue(dsnName, driverName);          
    // Create new key in odbc.ini with dsn name and add values        
    var dsnKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(ODBC_PATH + dsnName);        
    if (dsnKey == null) 
{
throw new Exception("ODBC Registry key for DSN was not created"); 
}             
dsnKey.SetValue("Database", database);         
dsnKey.SetValue("Description", description);         
dsnKey.SetValue("Driver", driverPath);         
dsnKey.SetValue("LastUser", "sa");         
dsnKey.SetValue("Server", server);         
dsnKey.SetValue("Database", database);
dsnKey.SetValue("username", "sa");
dsnKey.SetValue("password", "system123#");
dsnKey.SetValue("Trusted_Connection", trustedConnection ? "Yes" : "No");
```

Comment: Why do you need a DSN? A connection string can usually be used instead and is just a string

Comment: There are DSN setup on my PC that are not setup on other's.  Was just thinking if someone else were to run the app, they would need the same DSN?

Comment: I think Alex's question is was that normally when connecting to SQL Server you don't use ODBC, you use the native client built in to .NET in the [`System.Data.SqlClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace and therefor do not need to create a DSN.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - Okay that makes sense.  Yes I understand that.  But I am needing to install DSN so that when an access database is launched the linked table will be able to be 'read' on the other PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just exporting registry key from my PC and then launching it on the loadevent() on the PC that would need it.